# Ubuntu 19.10 Stellarium and Telescope Control

Tags: 19.10

I am running Ubuntu 19.10 Desktop, flavour Eoan Ermine:

I was having trouble getting a connection to my EQ3/2 Synscan hand controller. It was a faulty HC.

I now have a replacement HC which connects properly to Stellarium. I can now slew the scope, however, it will only slew to targets in approximately half of the sky; if I try to get it to acquire a target in the problem half of the sky, Stellarium then loses lock, meaning that slewing to a target in the working half of the sky, it points entirely the wrong way. I have equatorial selected, and allow auto flipping in the Synscan HC: this is on my Ubuntu Linux laptop ( it also behaves in the same way on my Windows laptop). Very odd, I can't see how to correct this. Do you think it is a Stellarium or hand controller issue? I have also updated the Synscan to the latest version: 4.39.10, which made no difference. Slewing with the HC is not a problem, it does what it is told.

Could someone please offer a solution to this please?

Comment: "this is on my Ubuntu Linux laptop ( it also behaves in the same way on my Windows laptop)" This would have me to believe it is not an operating system issue. " Do you think it is a Stellarium or hand controller issue?" w/o any knowledge about this device I lean towards yes :D We here are likely not the best audience for this. How about posting it here too: https://www.cloudynights.com/forum/66-mounts/

Comment: Ok thank you. I have posted on the Cloudynights forum